# Background color is not rendering for the created nodes

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, frontend, path-finding

I am trying to implement Path Finding Visualizer tutorial by Clement . I am new with the react. The color for the start and the end node is not getting rendered.

Please take a look at my files:

PathVisualizer.css :

```
.grid{
    margin: 500px 500 500;
    margin-top: 100px;
}
```

PathVisualizer.jsx :

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import Node from './Node/Node';
import './Node/Node.css'

import './PathfindingVisualizer.css';


export default class PathfindingVisualizer extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={
        nodes: [],
        };
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        const nodes=[];
       
        for(let row=0; row<20; row++){
            const currentRow=[];
            for(let col=0; col<50; col++){
                const currentNode={
                    col,
                    row,
                    isStart : row === 10 && col === 5,
                    isFinish : row === 10 && col === 45 ,
                };
                
                currentRow.push(currentNode);
            }
            nodes.push(currentRow);
        }
        this.setState({nodes});
    }
    render(){
        const {nodes}=this.state;
        console.log(nodes);

        return(
            <div className="grid">
                {nodes.map((row,rowIdx)=>{
                    return(
                        <div key={rowIdx}>
                            {row.map((node,nodeIdx) => {
                            const {isStart, isFinish} = node;
                            return(
                                
                                <Node>
                                    key={nodeIdx}
                                    isStart={isStart}
                                    isFinish={isFinish}
                                    test={'foo'}
                                    test={'kappa'}
                                </Node>
                            );
                        })}
                        </div>
                    );
                    })}
                
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Node.css :

```
.node {
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    grid-gap: 20px;
    outline: 1px solid rgb(94, 93, 93);
    display: inline-block;
  }

.node-finish {

  background-color: rgba(181, 6, 6, 0.751) !important;
}

.node-start {
  background-color: rgb(4, 178, 4)!important;
}
```

Node.jsx :

```
import React, {Component} from "react";

import './Node.css';

export default class Node extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={}
    }

    render(){
        const {isFinish, isStart} = this.props
        const extraClassName = isFinish 
        ? 'node-finish'
        : isStart ? 'node-start'
        : '';
        return <div className ={`node ${extraClassName}`}></div>
        
    }

}

export const DEFAULT_NODE={
    row:0,
    col:0,
};
```

These are my files. I am getting the output of the grid rendered correctly. But the node color for that specific mentioned nodes are not changing. Please help me out in the same.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am very curious about this. I tried color rendering on my side but it works well.
You should check the nodes, isStart and isFinish props.

Oh you have wrong code in here.

```
<Node>
   key={nodeIdx}
   isStart={isStart}
   isFinish={isFinish}
   test={'foo'}
   test={'kappa'}
</Node>
```

This should be like below.

```
<Node
   key={nodeIdx}
   isStart={isStart}
   isFinish={isFinish}
   test={'foo'}
   test={'kappa'}>
</Node>
```